# Как убрать вертикальную белую полосу при перелистывании слайдера Bootstap

Tags: css, bootstrap

подскажите, пожалуйста.

При смене изображений в слайдере Bootstrap появляется вот такая вертикальная полоска. Как мне ее убрать, не могу понять?

Скрин во вложении, а ссылка на сайт - https://xn----8sbkcccbsf1ardia8bhj9u.xn--p1ai/

Я пробовал эффект поменять на carousel-fade, но картинка не растворяется, а все также перелистывается

HTML:

```
    <!-- Включение слайдера -->
    <div class="container carousel-wrap">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide carousel-fade posit-abs " data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="banner" src="/local/templates/.default/img/1.png" alt="First slide" style="padding:0px;margin:0px">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="banner" src="/local/templates/.default/img/2.png" alt="Second slide" style="padding:0px;margin:0px">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="banner" src="/local/templates/.default/img/3.png" alt="Third slide" style="padding:0px;margin:0px">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="banner" src="/local/templates/.default/img/1.png" alt="Fwo slide" style="padding:0px;margin:0px">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="banner" src="/local/templates/.default/img/2.png" alt="Fife slide" style="padding:0px;margin:0px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуй сменить скорость пролистования картинки.Какая карусель у тебя?

Comment: data-interval="10000" например ? не помогает

Comment: какую карусель используеш?

Comment: Друг, правда не знаю как ответить Код сверху добавил в вопрос

Comment: Тогда создай, пожалуйста, пример на codesandbox или stackblitz, с полным кодом , включая css

Comment: Помог ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1027894/345744 .

Answer (score 0):

У вас, при смене изображений, текущему и следующему item-у добавляется и тут же удаляется класс `.left` при свайпе вправо и `.right` соответственно при свайпе влево. "Перебейте" их.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]